# how to set badge on bottom bar navigation?

Tags: android, badge, bottombar

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_lang:
                    toolbar.setTitle("Language");
                    fragment = new LangFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_paid:
                    toolbar.setTitle("Paid");
                    fragment = new PaidFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_unpaid:
                    toolbar.setTitle("UnPaid");
                    fragment = new UnpaidFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_declined:
                    toolbar.setTitle("Declined");
                    fragment = new DeclinedFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
```

how to add badge on menu icon in fragment. I tried more examples but all are in activity i need to implement that in fragment. how to implement the xml for badge on menu. I added the image also. that is my tool bar menu.please help how to do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073610/7254873

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use a library such as this 
https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

you can easily show notification on bottom navigation icon

```
bottomNavigation.setNotification("1", 3);
```

Read more here: https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/blob/master/README.md

Comment: how to use the above library inside of project

Comment: It is very simple, `dependencies {
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
}` please look at this step by step guide here  https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio